# JQuery Accordion - how to collapse or open all of the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jquery accordion to place multiple accordion menus on my page.
There are many instances of these menus that are shown/hidden depending on a input selection on the same page.

When I click to collapse the accordion, I would like that accordion along with all other accordions with the same class name to collapse as well.
Vice versa for opening the accordion.

So far:

```
$('.accordion_class').on('accordionactivate',function(event, ui){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var active = $(this).accordion( "option", "active" );
    if (active === 0)
    {
        $('.accordion_class').accordion('option','active',true);
    }else
    {
        $('.accordion_class').accordion('option','active',false);
    }
})
```

Apparently, `active` is either `false` or `0` when the accordion is open or collapsed, respectively (i believe).
I have no idea if I am using `event.preventDefault();` `event.stopPropagation();` correctly. I would love a quick explanation.
When I use this code, it runs through each instance of the class name accordions and either opens or closes the accordion for each instance. However, since it does this for each instance, it opens and closes the menu multiple times on a single click.

How do I get it to only perform this action once?
How do I escape/break out of a jquery $(class).on('active',function(){}) whatever this is called?

Comment: Open all /close all or open all that's closed/close all that is open?

Comment: @zer00ne open all with same class name and/or close all with same class name.